# Equilibrium solution to system of 4 ODEs with 6 parameters

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, code-request

I have the following system of 4 ODEs of 4 state variables $(M_{U},M_{R},F_{N},F_{M})$ and 6 parameters $(\alpha,b,\gamma,\mu_{M},\delta,\mu_{F})$ that I am trying to find the equilibrium solution for:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} M_{U}=\alpha b F_{M}-\gamma M_{U}-\mu_{M}M_{U} \\
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} M_{R}=\gamma M_{U}-\mu_{M}M_{R} \\
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} F_{N}=(1-\alpha)b F_{M}-\delta F_{N}-\mu_{F}F_{N} \\
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} F_{M}=\delta F_{N}-\mu_{F}F_{M}
\end{align}
$$
I am a complete newcomer to Mathematica and have been going off the example I found here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78785/software-to-find-the-equilibria-of-a-set-of-differential-equations, but my code here produced nothing

```
Refine[Solve[{
   α b Fm - γ Mu - μm  Mu == 0, 
   γ Mu - μm Mr ==  0, 
   (1 - α) b Fm - δ Fn - μf Fn == 0, 
   δ Fn - μf Fm == 0}, 
   {Mu, Mr, Fn, Fm}, Reals] // 
       Simplify[#, α > 0 && b > 0 && γ > 0 && μm > 0 && δ > 0 && μf >  0]]
```

I also tried to define the equations as their own variable and then use DSolve on it, which also didn't work.

```
sysODE = {Mu'[t] == α*b*Fm[t] - γ*Mu[t] - μm*Mu[t], 
Mr'[t] == γ*Mu[t] - μm*Mr[t], 
Fn'[t] == (1 - α)*b*Fm[t] - δ*Fn[t] - μf*Fn[t], 
Fm'[t] == δ*Fn[t] - μf*Fm[t]}
Dsolve[sysODE, {Mu[t], Mr[t], Fn[t], Fm[t]}, t]
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? I thought since I am just looking for the non-trivial steady state solution it should be fairly easy to get right. Thank you!!!

Comment: This looks similar to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95277/finding-equilibria-to-a-system-of-3-odes-with-11-unknown-parameters-looking-for.  But it is much simpler because the equations are linear and permit a complete symbolic time dependent solution.

Comment: Both computations contain typos.  In the first, replace `#` by `# &` to obtain `{{Mu -> 0, Mr -> 0, Fn -> 0, Fm -> 0}}`.  In the second, replace `Dsolve` by `DSolve`.

Comment: Thank you @Dr.WolfgangHintze, I studied that example which is where I got the idea for my second code snippet. Is there any reason why Dsolve provides the equations I am looking for versus Solve which simply returns that each state variable goes to 0? My results: http://i.imgur.com/yOf9HzJ.png

Comment: @slwu89 DSolve gives you correctly the general solution to the sytem of 4 ODEs. The solution consists of Long expressions which are sums of exponentials which go to 0 when t -> inf. In order to see this better, set explicit simple numerical values (constants like 0 or 1/2 etc.) to all parameters and initial values. The question is also what you are really after, what is the physical meaning of your equations?